# Reading bed file integers from bytes

Tags: python, byte, decode

I've created a tab delimited bed file using the following code

```
    def raw_data_file(sample_name, chrom):
    data = []
    with open (('{}_{}_raw_data2.bed'.format(sample_name, chrom)),'w') as text_file:
    for (i, zone) in enumerate(zones):
        select = final_data[i]
        for x in select:
            row = [chrom, int(zone[1][0]), int(zone[1][1]), zone[0], x]
            text_file.write("\t".join(map(str, row))+"\n")
```

I then open it using

```
    with open ('HG00148_1_raw_data2.bed', 'rb') as f:
    rawdata = [x.decode('utf-8').split('\t') for x in f.read().splitlines()]
```

The data show lines with chromosome number, start point, end point, zone name and a list of associated data (read position, p-value, reads)

When trying to the read position of line zero using:

```
    rawdata[0][4][1]
```

my code returns 7 instead of 755255 (treats each character as a byte). What should I change either in my encoding or decoding of the bed file for the read position to be returned correctly?

Thanks

Comment: can't you use `csv` module and use `tab` as separator ?

Comment: what do you see when you get `rawdata[0][4]` ?

Comment: @furas I see  "('755222', '-0.65', '0.41', '9', '1', '2')" - the data i'm trying to retrieve is 755222

Comment: I need the file in bed format as I intend to index it using tabix - not easily done from a csv file

Comment: Please show the first lines of the bed file as it could help to understand what actually happens.

Comment: First 3 lines:['1', '1550282', '1550972', 'Peak139332', "('1550282', '-1.24', '1.12', '12', '1', '2')"]
['1', '1550282', '1550972', 'Peak139332', "('1550283', '-1.24', '1.12', '12', '1', '2')"]
['1', '1550282', '1550972', 'Peak139332', "('1550284', '-1.24', '1.12', '12', '1', '2')"]

Comment: it looks like one string, not tuple with elements. So you have to convert this string to tuple. ie. `a = eval("('755222', '-0.65', '0.41', '9', '1', '2')")` and then you can get `a[0]` - but it will be string '755222' - if you need numer then `int(a[0])`

Comment: @furas Thanks!! That's exactly what i was looking for!